Why is there a sharp divide between paramagnetism and diamagnets in the periodic table?
On the periodic table* basically everything to the right or the same group as copper is diamagnetic, whereas anything to the left is paramagnetic or magnetically ordered! Why is this?
It is definitely not just a matter of crystal structure or molecular vs polymer chain vs network solid!
I also consider red electronic band structure but still could not discern why?
(Also, why are aluminium and beryllium the only exceptions**)
** hydrogen and helium can also be exceptions if they are put a top lithium and beryllium.
* long form with inner transition metals between “alkaline earths” and outer transition

Do you have a reference for which elements are diamagnetic and which are paramagnetic?

I thought everything was diamagnetic, albeit weakly. This effect is just overwhelmed if the material is also ferro or paramagnetic.

The separation is remarkable; to the left all elements except Hydrogen and Beryllium are classified as paramagnetic, and to the right all elements except Oxygen and Aluminium are classified as diamagnetic.
The fact that it is such a sharp divide is unexplained, it would seem.
Magnetic properties hinge on whether electrons have opportunity to pair up or not:
Diamagnetic, Paramagnetic, and Ferromagnetic Materials
When electrons have opportunity to pair up: diamagnetism.
When there are unpaired electrons: magnetism.
(With subdivision: three elements, Iron, Cobalt and Nickel form Domains: the domains give ferromagnetism; the other elements with unpaired electrons don't form domains: paramagnetism.)
So we have this vertical divide in the periodic system in opportunity of electrons to pair up.

There is the correlation of binding energy of outer electrons and column of the periodic table.
Hydrogen is is different from the other elements in that column of the periodic system in the following way: the binding energy of the electron of Hydrogen is sufficient to support a covalent bond. It would appear that that covalent bond is what allows the electrons of the Hydrogen molecule to behave as an electron pair.
The case of Beryllium is surprising. Beryllium is metallic; Beryllium doesn't form a diatomic Beryllium molecule. Still, the diamagnetism of Beryllium indicates the electrons do have opportunity to pair up.

For the column of Copper and to the right of Copper we see that all elements are classified as diamagnetic, with the exceptions of Oxygen and Aluminium.
About the paramagnetic property of Oxygen molecules:
The supposition that Oxygens atoms form a double bond is an oversimplification. For most elements the oversimplification is inconsequential, but for the magnetic properties of the Oxygen molecule a deeper description is necessary.
Source for the Oxygen case:
Libretexts: Chem 260: Inorganic Chemistry (Girard)
Section 2.4 Molecular Orbital Theory

Catena trioxygen, aka ozone is diamagnetic in gaseous state no?

Why is magnesium paramagnetic, yet zinc, and beryllium diamagnetic?

Also, interesting to note that every row before transition has exceptions
